# Подклчить колонки к двум источникам

Tags: аудио, железо

Хочу подключить колонки к двум источникам звука одновременно. Будут они воспроизводить одновременно оба источника или будет некий способ переключения между ними (типа выключателя) не важно.

Нагуглил, что самый простой (варварский) метод - просто спаять провода. Но паять ничего не собираюсь. Можно ли найти подходящее готовое устройство? Т. е. либо просто что-то типа разветвителя, но наоборот, либо оно же, но с переключателем. Никаких дополнительных наворотов не надо. Кстати, как такая штука называется?

Также пришло в голову использовать адаптер для объединения наушников и микрофона - типа того, что на фото. Что будет, если оба его конца воткнуть в источники звука, а в него воткнуть колонки? Или нужно что-то другое?

[image: фото]

Comment: Обратитесь на форум радиолюбителей

Comment: @Sergey, я в электронике вообще не разбираюсь, паять не умею, к тому же нечем. Хочу уже готовый проводок за адекватную цену (а не "самое простое ... микшер за 8К", как нагуглилось на одном из форумов).

Comment: При примитивном соединение шнурами, к друг другу окажутся подключены два источника звука, точнее две электрические цепи. Не являясь радиолюбителем, подозреваю, что они могут пагубно повлиять друг на друга, и лучше спрошу опытного радиолюбителя, чем доверяться балбесу-одмину или кодеру, будь он автаритет на стековерфлов хоть 100500-го уровня.

Comment: Если надо только переключение, то достаточно тумблера спаренного/строенного (по количеству каналов). Паять не хотите - ищите готовый. 8к это явно перебор даже по нынешним ценам. За такую сумму наверно можно найти дешёвый многоканальный av-ресивер. Вам же нужен примитивный коммутатор. Не думаю, чтобы они так дорого стоили. Зайдите в ближайший магазин радиотехники и спросите там. Стоят поди рублей 200.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если просто "спаять" ничего хорошего не выйдет.
Выход оконечного усилителя заточен под периферию определённого реактивного сопротивления(Выход на колонки обычно 4 Ω, на наушники порядка 16 Ω/32 Ω/300 Ω).

Рассогласование выходного сопротивления с сопротивлением нагрузки резко ухудшает качество усиления, потому что выходные каскады усилителей меняют режим работы(вплоть до выхода из строя!). В вашем случае, нужно ещё учитывать взаимное влияние источников звука.

Вам нужно таки определиться, что вам нужно:

- Микшер источников звука
  [image]
- Переключатель источников звука:
  [image]
  [image]

С переключателем всё намного проще - в каждый момент времени работает только одна нагрузка. Его даже можно включать в обратном направлении :)

Comment: Достаточно переключателя. _"Выход на колонки обычно 4 Ω, на наушники порядка 16 Ω/32 Ω"_ - не понял этот момент. Разъём же один и тот же?

Comment: Разъём и импеданс слабо кореллируют. 3.5" джеки обычно вешаются на высокоомные маломощные каскады(линейный выход). 4/8/16 относятся к оконечным усилителям и слабо относятся к вопросу. Подробнее можно почитать тут:  [ГОСТ 24838-87. 2.7 Согласование АС с УНЧ](http://vladimir-sergin.narod.ru/ntd/gost/gost_24838-87.pdf), если интересно. =)

Answer (score 2):

Устройство которое может смешивать 2 или более канала, а так же управлять их громкостью, отключать или включать определённые каналы в режим соло - называется микшер.

Comment: А если всё что находится в "а так же" не требуется? Насколько я представляю, микшер - достаточно сложное и дорогостоящее устройство, а интересует всего лишь 3 куска провода с переключателем и не более того.

Comment: Вариантов масса: Если один канал комп, второй канал можно воткнуть в его линейный вход и комп сам смешает эти 2 канала. Если вообще просто: Покупаете двухполосный переключатель в любом электромагазине за 20 рублей. У него 3 контакта, к первому контакту крепим плюс канала1, ко второму(по середите) плюс который пойдёт к колонкам, к третьему плюс канала2. второй провод от колонок заземляете во что угодно.

Comment: провод от гарнитуры не будет работать, так как на выход будет идти звук только от провода на котором нарисованы наушникик.